# Slimes,bouncy green blobs

Tags: creature-design, earth-like

I'm writing a comic where semi transparent green blobs called slimes live on an earth like planet. These slimes are psychic and can hold things with their minds. They speak English.

What must I do to make them as believable as possible with minimal explaining.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. To get a useful answer, consider asking about a specific aspect of your slimes believably.

Comment: If it were me, I'd change the question title: Evolution of a transparent blob creature. That being said, you don't really need to explain them. There are living slime blobs. They are intelligent. And psychic. Magic! OK, makes sense. If you want to have an idea of how they work so you can keep it consistent then that's a good idea, but you don't need to tell you're readers unless the charters need to know.

Answer (score 1):

As for theme knowing English, perhaps they psychically constructed the language to communicate with whoever makes contact with them. In order to be intelligent creatures, perhaps their whole body works as a functional "brain" with signals flowing freely through them.

Just ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Intelligent, psychic, telekinetic slimes are impossible in our universe or one similar to it.

Your best bet is to simply not explain them, or at least not how they work.

You could explain part of them with other parts of them, e.g. if it seems particularly strange that they speak english or are intelligent you could explain that through their psychic attributes; by reading the minds of humans they learned english and/or adapted to be more similar to them (intelligent).